# How to configure L, ST, C... propeties in my Fabric certificates when creating the Fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I see this logs in my peer node:

```
2019-12-06 12:47:51.496 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 8c9 streaming call completed grpc.service=gossip.Gossip grpc.method=GossipStream grpc.peer_address=10.244.0.1:35758 grpc.peer_subject="CN=blockchain-hapeer1.mydomain.net,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US" error=EOF grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=1.803311ms
```

I have not configured L, ST or C in my certificate creation process (cryptogen and configtxgen commands). Where should I configure that so the certificate is generate not with those default values (San Francisco, California, ...) but with the correct ones for my country and organization?
configtx.yaml... crypto-config.yaml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go in `crypto-config.yaml`: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py/blob/master/test/fixtures/e2e_cli/crypto-config.yaml.

Anyway, you usually don't care much about that until something more similar to a pre-production environment, and in that case you should use a CA (normally Fabric-CA) instead of `cryptogen`. When using Fabric-CA, you must check `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml` in the CA itself (in its `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME`) and `fabric-ca-client-config.yaml` in its client (in its `FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME`).

Comment: Thanks @kekomal . I have followed this tutorial from IBM to create the network in Kubernetes: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes It creates the  Fabric-CA pod whild also uses cryptogen to generate the certificates (so I will configure them in crypto-config.yaml as in the first link you pasted. I wonder if there is any specififc problem of using cryptogen approach in a basic production Fabric network. Thanks for any clarifications on this.

Comment: OK. When employing Fabric-CAs, there is no need of using `cryptogen`. I've heard of people that first generate the basic cryptographic material for their network via `cryptogen` and then launch the Fabric-CA based on that material. I don't know if that's the case (no time to dive into the project). I don't like that approach. It saves time, but the identities that should be associated to the material generated via `cryptogen` are not registered in the CA DB, so that you cannot manage those identities later if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, kekomal. That is the approach I have taken for my Dev environment.  I will look for some tutorials on how to migrate from using cryptogen to fabric-ca crypto material. Any links or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `CA` section to the various orgs:

```
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Org1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "CA"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of the CA for this
    # organization.  This entry is a Spec.  See "Specs" section below for details.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CA:
    #    Hostname: ca # implicitly ca.org1.example.com
    #    Country: US
    #    Province: California
    #    Locality: San Francisco
    #    OrganizationalUnit: COP
    #    StreetAddress: address for org # default nil
    #    PostalCode: postalCode for org # default nil
```